# How to set value in dropdown while selecting field in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to dynamically change the options of a HTML dropdown menu based on which customer address city a user selects - for example, I have a JSON data.

```
addObj 
Array(4)
0: {addressee: 'Customer2', country: 'US', state: 'NH', zip: '03103', city: 'Bedford', …}
1: {addressee: 'NB Demo Customer', country: 'US', state: 'MA', zip: '01432', city: 'Devens', …}
2: {addressee: 'Customer1', country: 'US', state: 'MA', zip: '01730', city: 'Bedford', …}
3: {addressee: 'Nb Demo check', country: 'US', state: 'MA', zip: '01748', city: 'Hopkinton', …}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

and I have image drop down menu.
**image 1:**

[image: shipping dropdown]

So, here first word before delivery are city names.

another image selecting customer addresses :
**image 2:**

[image: customer addresses]

if the user select any of customer1,customer2,nb demo customer then based on city and state I need to compare and append that particular dropdown in select shipping method.

Likewise, eg: city : Bedford, state : MA then shipping method dropdown should be Beford MA delivery.

I am stuck with a function similar to this one (I am new to web dev and an largely unfamiliar with javascript,Jquery and its syntax):

```
if (activeAddObj) {
        debugger;
        if (activeAddObj.city) {
        
            filtered = _.filter(setup.shipping, function(data) {
                return data.name === activeAddObj.city + ' ' + 'Delivery';
            });
            
        shippingmethod = filtered[0].name;
        shippingmethodId = filtered[0].internalId;
        
            console.log('shippingmethod', shippingmethod);
            console.log('shippingmethodId', shippingmethodId);

            $("#delivery-method-check").prop("checked", true);
            $(".delivery-method-container").show();

            var delivery = jQuery("#shipping-method");
            console.log('delivery', delivery);

            var html = "";

            if (delivery.html().trim().length <= 0) {
                delivery.append($("<option />").val(shippingmethodId).text(shippingmethod));
            }
            jQuery("#shipping-method").append(html);
        
        }
        
        }
```

activeAddObj is

```
address1: "9955"
address2: "9955"
addressee: "NB Demo Customer"
addrsid: "89242"
city: "Devens"
internalid: "89263"
phone: "(987) 987-9870"
state: "MA"
zip: "01432"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

setup.shipping is

[image: shipping values]

```
            <div class="shipping-addr-container">
                <div class="shipping-addr-div">
                    <label for="" class="shipping-addr-head"> Ship To</label>
                    <span class="ship-to-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="ship-to-check" value="" name="update" class="switch_1">
                        <span class="switch-after"></span>
                    </span>
                    
                    <div class="addr-main-container" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="addr-container">
                            
                        </div>  
                    </div>                          
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="delivery-method-main-container">
                <div class="delivery-method-div">
                    <label for="" class="delivery-method-head">Shipping Method:</label>
                    <span class="ship-to-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="delivery-method-check" value="" name="update" class="switch_1">
                        <span class="switch-after"></span>
                    </span>
                    
                    <div class="delivery-method-container" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="select-delivery-method">
                            <label>Select Shipping method:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="shipping-method">
                                
                            </select>
                        </div>  
                    </div>                          
                </div>
            </div>
```

my conclusion is whatever we select any customer address(image 2) based on that city and state we need to compare and select and show dropdown automatically. Please advice me in programming.